# EDGAR API using C#

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a personal project involving SEC's EDGAR API. Its a small project. All Im trying to do is build a windows from app using C# where the user can search a company name to retrieve its CIK.Then use the CIK to search up 10K and 10Q filings in a given yea range. All communication is through EDGAR public API. But I am very much abeginner and am trying to learn through this project. I just need some kind of advice on how to get strated with this project.

I get the part where I can use the API to retrieve the data but dont know how to search up indexes using API's. Im totally lost in the sauce. I am basically looking for some advice on how to structure the project.